# Make a find prime number function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

Make a find prime number `function` in javascript. I want to let it display the values to `textarea` whenever it finds a prime number.

However, it will only show the result when the function is fully executed.

Here is my code:

```js
 

let start = performance.now()
        let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
        let time = document.getElementById('time')
        let texts = document.getElementById('texts')
        let amount = document.getElementById('amount')
        let status = document.getElementById('status')
        let logs = [];
        let number = 0
        let prime = [];
        
        function check(){ 
        status.textContent = 'processing'
        amount.textContent = 'processing'
        time.textContent = 'processing'
        textarea.textContent =logs
        setTimeout(function(){reallycheckprimenumber()},0)
        }
        function reallycheckprimenumber(){
        number = 0;
        let start = performance.now()
        let value = texts.value
        if(value ==''){
            value = texts.placeholder;
        }
        for (var i = 0;i<value;i++){
            time.textContent = ''
            amount.textContent = ''
            var nums = 2;
             for (let x = 0;x<=i/2;x++){
                if(nums>3){
                        break;
                    }
                if(i!==0 && i!==1 && i !== x){
                    if(i%x === 0){
                        nums++;
                    }  
                    }
                }
             if(nums === 3){
                prime.push(i)
                textarea.textContent += prime
                number +=1
                }
            if(i === value-1){
            status.textContent = 'done'
            let end = performance.now()
            time.textContent = (end-start).toFixed(5) +'ms'
            amount.textContent = number
                     }
          }
        }
    check()
```

```html
 

<h1>Get Prime number application:</h1>
        <h2>Prime Number: <span></span></h2>
        <h3 >Processing Time: <span id = 'time'>0 ms</span></h3>
        <h3>Number: <span id = 'amount'>0</span></h3>
        <h3>Status: <span id = 'status'>Processing</span></h3>
        <label for = 'texts'>Enter the range you want to get number from</label>
        <input type = 'text' id = 'texts' placeholder = '100'>
        <input type = 'button' id = 'button' value = 'set' onclick = 'check()'>
        <textarea readonly></textarea>
```

I have tried several ways to make the application displays prime number while it is finding other prime number. However, I failed.

I found that only `console` will work.
I really have no idea on how to solve this problem.

Anyone have an idea and know how to solve it?
Thanks so much for any helps and supports

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful. https://www.tabnine.com/academy/javascript/how-to-use-settimeout/

Comment: @AaronJ, the `setTimeout` function is absolutely a good way to do that, but there is no way for me to use in the `for` loop where `if(nums === 3){` (check if it is a prime number. I have already used it in `check()` function

Comment: Remember to [keep your posts focused](/help/how-to-ask): if your question is about how to update HTML, then the prime-finding is not relevant to the question. If it's about making your prime finding code work properly, then it doesn't matter what you do with the result once thing work. This is either a question about finding primes, or about how to make JS put a value on the page, but it shouldn't be about both =)

Comment: Library [primes-generator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/primes-generator) can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with 2,3 already, you do not have to check for them every time with `===` . It should be enough to check until the sqrt of the number. The below snippet will print the list to a textArea if it finds one.

Note that using setTimeout or any sort of fixed interval update does not seem like a good idea because prime numbers get sparse over time, which means it will take longer and longer to log something on the screen.

```js
(function(start){
    const list = start,
          myarea = document.getElementById("myarea");
    let nCurrent = start[start.length - 1];
    function recurse(){
        let _sqrt = Math.sqrt(nCurrent);
        for (let i = 2; i <= _sqrt; ++i) {
            if(!(nCurrent % i)){
                break;
            }
            if (i === Math.floor(_sqrt)){
                list.push(nCurrent);
                myarea.textContent = list.toString();
            }
        }
        nCurrent++;
    };
    setInterval(recurse,500);    
}([2,3]))
```

```html
<textArea id="myarea"></textArea>
```

Explanation:

1. Outer most function is an immediately invoked function expression (`iife`), which gets 1 parameter, a list to start with. In this case we start with `[2,3]`, first 2 primes.
2. Inside we create 3 variables:

   - the list, that holds all primes found until now
   - `nCurrent`, which is the current number we are checking if prime
   - `recurse`, a recursive function that will be called by setInterval.
3. For every `nCurrent`, lets say 120, it is sufficient to look until the sqrt of 120, and see whether numbers `<= sqrt(120)` divides 120. If it does, the operator `%` will return `0`, and `!(nCurrent % i)` will therefore return true (!0 is true). In that case we know this is not a prime number, we terminate early, increment `nCurrent` and wait until the next call of `recurse`.
4. If all the i's until `sqrt(nCurrent)` is tested and does not divide it, then we have a prime and we push it to the list.
5. `list.toString()` is defult stringification of an array in JS, which return all the elements joined by comma.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely a very amazing, but could you do an explanation of your algorithm? It is very tricky for me to figure out how does this algorithm work. Thank you for very much!

Comment: @Shawn I added some explanation underneath

Comment: If you're finding all primes up to a certain value, you will almost certainly be much better served by implementing a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @Phylogenesis, very nice idea to trade CPU time to memory, latter is cheaper. I learned something. thanks!